What's the meaning of the "snub face" in this senttence?
In this extract from Fat City by By Leonard Gardner, he is a boxer, so does "snub face" mean he has a harsh look or something like that?

Short, trim, his snub face thrust forward now with a look of intense concentration, the remnants of his black, oiled hair combed back from the temples, he rocked on his toes, jingling change in his yellow-ochre slacks.


Merriam-Webster: adjective blunt, stubby. a snub nose. Also see (from Google image search) nose shapes.

It is normally an adjective used to describe a nose.  If applied to "face" it would mean "a face with a snub nose".  You can check this in a dictionary.  You have not added the source of the quote to your question.

Its Fat City
By Leonard Gardner https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Fat_City/ZYiwDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Short%2C%20trim%2C%20his%20snub%20face%22&pg=PT24&printsec=frontcover

@WeatherVane thank you. So it could mean someone whose face is fat and short?

@JamesK than you. Yes it is from fat city. He is a boxer, so he  have harsh look or something like that. Then here " a face with a snub nose" wouldn't be appropriate.

"Snub" as an adjective is normally only used to describe someone's nose as short or turned up (in contrast to the usual nose shape of Europeans). Here it would mean "a face with a snub nose".  While some people naturally have a snub nose, since he is a boxer, he probably got his in a fight.  Boxers often have snub noses, because the nose can get broken and change shape when it is hit.

